# Frame with round corners does not look the same in Working and Printout environments

Tags: output-formatting, printing

I want to generate some graphics that contain framed texts with rounded corners that display correctly in the `Working` and `PrintOut` environment. For example,

```
Graphics[{Inset@Framed[Text[Foobar], RoundingRadius -> 15]}]
```

generates the first of the following two boxes in a notebook, which is what I want.

[image: Framed Text in Working and PrintOut]

However, when I export my notebook to pdf or print it then the frame will look like the second box in the picture, which I do not want. I can fix the second box by using a smaller `RoundingRadius` but then the box looks almost like a rectangular frame in my notebook.

How can I get a frame with rounded corners that looks like the first example the `Working` and `PrintOut` environment?

(I do not want to use the Working environment when printing because then font sizes and such will also change.)

Comment: I am running V10.3.1 on OS X. I can not reproduce your problem. The framed text looks the same in both the Working environment, the Printout environment and in saved PDF document. BTW, you have not need to use `Inset`. `Graphics[Text[Framed[Foobar, RoundingRadius -> 15]]]` will give the same image as the one you post in your question.

Comment: I can confirm what @m_goldberg found on Mac. Just a guess: does it help if you set the `ImageSize` to a fixed value? Or perhaps try `SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], WindowSize -> All]` - these guesses are based on the hunch that the rounding radius (and/or thickness) is referenced to a different external length scale (outside the plot). In any case, it looks like a bug on Windows.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Setting `ImageSize->{72}` did not help and neither did changing the `WindowSize`. Also, I am using Mathematica 10.2.0.0 and Win10.

Comment: By the way, using `Text@Framed` is not identical to `Inset@Framed@Text`. Different (default) fonts are used. (But your suggestion seems better.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As m_goldberg and Jens could not reproduce the problem on Mathematica 10.3.1 I updated my Mathematica and it turns out that the behavior of Mathematica depends on the version.

```
Graphics[Text[Framed[Foobar, RoundingRadius -> 7]]]
```

yields the following. From left to right: V10.2 Notebook, V10.2 PrintOut, V10.3.1 Notebook, V10.3.1 Printout

[image]

So the problem still exists in V10.3.1 but it is not nearly as pronounced.

It seems that the problem originates from a buggy implementation of the `Magnification` in Mathematica. (Someone not using a 4K-display would perhabs not notice it.) The line width of the frame scales faster with `Magnification` then the fonts. The same framed text at `Magnification->5` looks like the following in V10.3.1:

[image]

This is even worse in V10.2: Left `Magnification` 1 and right 5, scaled to the same size (in gimp).

[image]

(The `Magnification` in the 4 samples above is `2`.)

Comment: (+1) A workaround is to set `AbsoluteThickness` for the `FrameStyle` (the default setting seems to be the relative `Thickness`): `Graphics[Text[Framed[Foobar, RoundingRadius -> 7, FrameStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[1]]]]`.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not a answer.

On my machine (Mathematica 10.0.2, Windows 7), I can reproduce the problem but it looks like a little bit different :

Working environment :

[image]

Printout environment :

[image]